# how to add an anchor after page reload

Tags: php, forms, submit, anchor

I have found this question asked before, and usually the answer suggests to insert the #MyAnchor inside the form tag, as the last piece in the action string... but in this case, in which the action string is very complicated, where exactly shall I place the anchor so the page reloads in the same place where the field was (and not on the top of the page)?

```
<div class="submit-form">
                <?php if (get_option('cap_api_key') != ""){?>
                     <?php 
                //newsletter signup
                if ($_SESSION['email_signup'] == "true"){
                    echo "Cadastro efetuado. Confira seu email.";                       $_SESSION['email_signup'] = ""; 
                }elseif ($_SESSION['email_signup'] == "bad email"){
                    echo "Por favor coloque um endereço de email válido."; ?>
                    <form method="post" action="<?php bloginfo( 'template_directory' ); ?>/includes/mailchimp.php?api_key=<?php echo get_option('cap_api_key'); ?>&list_id=<?php echo get_option('cap_list_id'); ?>"> 
                        <fieldset>
<label for="lb01">Participe do CSVB</label>
                            <div class="inp02"><input value="Email Address" id="lb01" name="email" type="text" /></div>
                            <input type="submit" class="btn-submit" value="submit" />
                        </fieldset>
                    </form><?php
                }else{?>
                    <form method="post" action="<?php bloginfo( 'template_directory' ); ?>/includes/mailchimp.php?api_key=<?php echo get_option('cap_api_key'); ?>&list_id=<?php echo get_option('cap_list_id'); ?>">
                        <a id="anchor" name="anchor"></a><fieldset>
                            <label for="lb01">Participe do CSVB</label>
                            <div class="inp02"><input value="Cadastre seu Email" id="lb01" name="email" type="text" /></div>
                            <input type="submit" class="btn-submit" value="submit" />
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
              <?php }} ?>

                </div><!--submit-form-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add an `id="field"` and browser will in most cases refresh to that anchor provided the url  has `#field`

Comment: This is correct.  It'll try to put it to the top of your viewport.   Your anchor references an ID tag somewhere on the page.